# Porting,Linux,C

Tags: c, linux, porting

I am getting this error while running this command

```
[root@himanshi busybox-1.20.2]# make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi- CONFIG_PREFIX=/home/himanshi/beagleboard_xm/target install
    /home/himanshi/beagleboard_xm/build/busybox-1.20.2/scripts/gcc-version.sh: line 11: arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc: command not found
      CC      applets/applets.o
    /bin/sh: arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc: command not found
    make[1]: *** [applets/applets.o] Error 127
make: *** [applets_dir] Error 2
```

Infact I am getting error COMMAND NOT FOUND for this also::
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-

Please assist me for solving this problem.
Thank you
Himanshi

Comment: it means you don't have a cross compiler with the prefix `arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-`. You should replace this prefix with the prefix of the name of the compiler that produces `arm` code on your system. This may require the installation of a package to do this

Answer (score 1):

you should put the path of `arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc` in the PATH environment variable like this:

```
PATH=$PATH:/path/to/compiler
export PATH
```